# python pandas Is it possible to run math/stats operations on categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas

I have converted a large df (large in relation to my available RAM) to categorical columns. This saved ~80% space in memory. Now I need to run math/stats operations on the data. Is there a way to run operations like `sum`, `mean`, `max`, and `rank` on categorical data in pandas?

## Create df

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['g1', 'u1', 0, 'single', 1],
                   ['g50', 'u92', '0', 'shared', '8'],
                   ['g50', 'u92', '0', 'shared', '1']], 
                  columns=['group', 'owner', 'failed','granted_pe', 'slots'])
df = (df.astype(dtype={'group':'str', 'owner':'str','failed':'int', 'granted_pe':'str', 'slots':'int'}))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  group owner  failed granted_pe  slots
0    g1    u1       0     single      1
1   g50   u92       0     shared      8
2   g50   u92       0     shared      1
```

## Convert to categorical

```
for feat in ('group', 'owner', 'failed', 'granted_pe', 'slots'):
    df[feat] = df[feat].astype('category')
```

## Get sum

```
df['slots_sum'] = df.groupby('group')['slots'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

"TypeError: Categorical cannot perform the operation sum"

Is there another way to perform this operation without converting the data back to int?

Comment: @jezrael, is there a way to run `mean` on categorical data when the data that was converted to categorical was numeric? I used categorical dtype to reduce the df's size in memory by ~80%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` here and merge back to original `df`

```
def return_sum(values):
    return(sum(values))

df = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group')['slots'].apply(return_sum)).reset_index(),on='group')
df = df.rename(columns={'slots_x': 'slots', 'slots_y': 'slot_sum'})
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  group owner failed granted_pe   slots  slots_sum
0    g1    u1      0     single       1        1
1   g50   u92      0     shared       8        9
2   g50   u92      0     shared       1        9
```

Note: `mean`, `max` etc methods are not meant for categorical data as it does not make sense.

Comment: I understand that "categorical" data is often str/object, but in this case the underlying data that I want to work on (e.g., "slots") is numeric. I'm using the type `category` only to save memory footprint. So I thought that it would be possible to compute on these values.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I run your code: "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 24, placement implies 1". `def return_sum(values):`  `return(sum(values))` 
`df['slots_sum'] = df.merge(pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('group')['slots']
                                             .apply(return_sum)).reset_index(), on='group')`

Comment: @KarlBaker assign df= df.merge..... Merge will return a dataframe not  a series. I have working code in the answer. Just copy pasting should work

Comment: Thanks, it works for the sum function. I guess for the rest I'll have to convert data back to numeric first.